# Break points do not work

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I am trying to debug JavaScript code in PhpStorm. I have installed the JetBrains IDE support extension for Chrome and added a JavaScript debug configuration in PhpStorm.

If I click debug, PhpStorm will open the page in Chrome browser and I can see JavaScript logs in console inside PhpStorm, however PhpStorm will not break at breakpoints..

Anyone can help?

Comment: Why not debug through chrome?

Comment: The look and feel, the background color and fonts.. its much better for my eyes